# How to extract a json element by condition?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a `JSON` object as follows:

```
  "links" : [ {
    "rel" : "first",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/first"
  }, {
    "rel" : "self",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/self"
  }, {
    "rel" : "next",
    "href" : "http://localhost:8080/next"
  }];
```

Now I'd like to get the `href` url where  `rel = "next"`.
Question: how could I get this with javascript?

In Java I'd loop through the array and create an inverse `HashMap<Rel, Href>`, and the call `map.get("next");`.

But how is this done in JS?

Comment: You could also create a map (object) in JS just like you'd do in Java if you plan on fetching these frequently. If not, you can simply use your loop to grab the one you want. It's such a short Array that I don't know if there would be much performance difference. Have you attempted a solution?

Comment: For a one-off I'd use `links.find(el => el.rel == 'next').href`...

Comment: not sure why this question was downvoted, anyway if i am not misunderstood the below should work.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.

```
var safe = {
    "links": [{
        "rel": "first",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/first"
    }, {
        "rel": "self",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/self"
    }, {
        "rel": "next",
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/next"
    }]
};

var i,
    l = safe.links.length;

for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
    if (safe.links[i].rel === 'next') {
        console.log(safe.links[i].href);
    }
}
```